# windows netstat shows mysql server state time wait

Tags: windows-7, tcp, netstat

What does it mean when windows `netstat -ano` shows this, and why there are four (more than 1).

[image: netstat -ano output]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Technet Info for netstat](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490947.aspx).

Also, if you want to have a closer look, check the [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) or [this article](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html).

> TIME_WAIT is an often misunderstood state in the TCP state transition
> diagram. It's a state that some sockets can enter and remain in for a
> relatively long length of time, if you have enough socket's in
> TIME_WAIT then your ability to create new socket connections may be
> affected and this can affect the scalability of your client server
> system. There is often some misunderstanding about how and why a
> socket ends up in TIME_WAIT in the first place, there shouldn't be,
> it's not magical.